# Converting numeric value with currency symbol back to Decimal with NumberFormat

Tags: java

I would like to convert a possibly Decimal value prefixed with currency symbol into only numeric value.
For example -
The value can be like any of the following

```
String s1 = "£32,847,676.65";
String s2 = "£3,456.00";
String s3 = "£831,209";
```

I would like the result after conversion to be like - `32847676.65`, `3456.00` and `831209`.
I tried using the `parse()` method of the NumberFormat in this way -

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.UK);
numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
Number num = nf.parse(s1);
double dd = num.doubleValue();
BigDecimal gg = new BigDecimal(dd);
System.out.println(gg);
```

But the result is - `32847676.649999998509883880615234375` which is not quite exactly the correct one.

I need it to be numeric so that may be I can perform some kind of calculation.
Can you guys guide me with what else can I try

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already parse the value correctly. The problem is this:

```
BigDecimal gg = new BigDecimal(dd);
```

You covnert the value to BigDecimal, and the rounding problems of doubles account for the decimal places after the dot. Use:

```
BigDecimal gg = new BigDecimal(dd).setScale(2);
```

or

```
BigDecimal gg = new BigDecimal(dd).setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesnt work. If I sysout `gg.toString()` or `gg.toPlainString()` it results in `3.3E+7` and `33000000`

Comment: @Swift-Tuttle: Sorry, please try this variant

Comment: Yeah, with the RoundingMode it works perfect. Thanks a lot. Appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

When playing with BigDecimal, the appropriate constructor is **BigDecimal(String val)**

```
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.UK);
    BigDecimal gg = new BigDecimal(nf.parse(s1).toString());
    System.out.println(gg);
```

BigDecimal(double val) does construct an **exact decimal representation** of the double value, which is not the human readable value you expected.

"The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One might assume that writing new BigDecimal(0.1) in Java creates a BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a double (or, for that matter, as a binary fraction of any finite length). Thus, the value that is being passed in to the constructor is not exactly equal to 0.1, appearances notwithstanding.
[...]
Therefore, it is generally recommended that the String constructor be used in preference to this one"

Source : [BigDecimal javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html?java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But the problem is the return of the `parse()` method of NumberFormat is a `Number`. So if somehow I am able to convert the result into a `String` as required I might not even use BigDecimal, thats not the issue here.

Comment: My earlier comment was before your code snippet. Yeah this does work. Still, I wonder if I can get the decimal places for `String s2 = "£3,456.00";`. Thanks though.

Comment: I will have a look on how to do it without BigDecimal use :)

Comment: @Swift-Tuttle if you want to keep decimal places, then BigDecimal is the class to use. But you don't have to convert it in number before, otherwise the ".00" will be lost at this time.

Comment: @Swift-Tuttle actually you should use BigDecimal due to the decimal representation. But NumberFormat is not the exact formatter you want, as it parses a String into a Number, loosing decimal information.
You should create your own parser (or reuse a Format child class) in order to produce the String you want, and constructs a proper BigDecimal with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following without BigDecimal or NumberFormat. ;)

```
String s1 = "£32,847,676.65";
// remove the £ and ,
String s2 = s1.replaceAll("[£,]", "");
// then turn into a double 
double d = Double.parseDouble(s2);
// and round up to two decimal places.
double value = (long) (d * 100 + 0.5) / 100.0;

System.out.printf("%.2f%n", value);
```

prints

```
32847676.65
```

If youw ant to avoid rounding error in your calculations but don't want the heavy weight BigDecimal you can use `long` cents.

```
// value in cents as an integer.
long value = (long) (d * 100 + 0.5);

// perform some calculations on value here

System.out.printf("%.2f%n", value / 100.0);
```

Comment: Well this is quite simple solution but I wonder is it a good solution. Dont get me worng, I mean you know when sometimes we use the so-called dirty solution instead of an OO or a pure programming approach, in that sense.

Comment: Many developers have a rule that whenever you have money, use BigDecimal.  However, in all the banks I have worked with, they use double or int/long.

Answer (score 0):

It is not guaranteed to work, but according to the NumberFormat API documentation, its getXyzInstance methods will return a DecimalFormat instance for "the vast majority of locales". This can probably be interpreted as "for all locales, unless proprietary locale service providers are installed".

If you can cast your NumberFormat to DecimalFormat, you can tell it to parse to a BigDecimal directly, reducing your code to:

```
DecimalFormat nf = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.UK);
nf.setParseBigDecimal(true);
BigDecimal gg = (BigDecimal) nf.parse(s1);
System.out.println(gg);
```

In this case, you will have no problem with the inaccuracy of binary floating point numbers.