# No apparent errors, but GUI still not working?

Tags: java, user-interface

I have this code:

```
private void discountButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    double purchasePrice, discount, discountAmount;
    DecimalFormat x = new DecimalFormat("$##.00");

    purchasePrice = Double.parseDouble(inputPurchase.getText());
    discount = 0.1;

    if (purchasePrice < 10) {
        outputDiscountAmount.setText(x.format(0));
        outputPrice.setText(x.format(purchasePrice));
    } else {
        outputDiscountAmount.setText(x.format(purchasePrice * discount));
        discountAmount = purchasePrice - Double.parseDouble(outputDiscountAmount.getText());
        outputPrice.setText(x.format(discountAmount));

        //Not sure whether the discountAmount variable should be in the "else" 
        //brackets or at the top.  If it is at the top nothing works.
        //If where it is presently seen, outputDiscountAmount works, but outputPrice doesn't.
        //Don't know what's wrong.
    }
}
```

that I'm doing as a GUI, and within JButton using NetBeans 8.2.

Can see with my comments, the `outputPrice` is not working.  I don't see any errors.
What is wrong?
The code is supposed to give the price of a 10% discount on a purchase above $10, and output the new cost.  If purchase is below $10, no discount.
Thanks

Comment: "the outputPrice is not working" meaning?

Comment: It is not outputting any numbers when I run the GUI.

Comment: Questions like this get asked all the time.  You will solve it very easily using a debugger and stepping through each line of code.  It's a very powerful tool you should use.  Please let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume purchasePrice = 10.00:

```
outputDiscountAmount.setText(x.format(purchasePrice * discount));
```

Now outputDiscountAmount = $1.00.

```
discountAmount = purchasePrice - Double.parseDouble(outputDiscountAmount.getText());
```

This line throws NumberFormatException because $1.00 is not a valid number.

Now we have identified the issue, you should be able to do the rest. 
Here is a useful link if you are not sure [how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485020/converting-numeric-value-with-currency-symbol-back-to-decimal-with-numberformat).

Answer (score 0):

You can't parse invalid characters(int this case '$') for a number. Your code is failing with NumberFormatException as mentioned in the other answer.

Find below, complete code which works. Here, the discount is calculated into a separate double variable and then formatted to display on the discount label.

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class PriceDiscountSwing implements ActionListener{

    private JLabel outputDiscountAmount;
    private JLabel outputPrice;

    private JTextField inputPurchase;

    private JButton discountButton;
    JFrame frame = null;

    public PriceDiscountSwing(){
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI(){
        frame = new JFrame ();

        inputPurchase = new JTextField(20);

        outputDiscountAmount = new JLabel();

        outputPrice = new JLabel();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(inputPurchase);
        panel.add(outputDiscountAmount);
        panel.add(outputPrice);

        discountButton = new JButton("Find Discount");
        discountButton.addActionListener(this);

        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(discountButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void discountButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        double purchasePrice, discount, discountAmount;
        DecimalFormat x = new DecimalFormat("$##.00");

        String priceEnterred = inputPurchase.getText();
        if (priceEnterred.trim().length() > 0){
            purchasePrice = Double.parseDouble(priceEnterred.trim());
            discount = 0.1;

            if (purchasePrice < 10) {
                outputDiscountAmount.setText("Discount: " + x.format(0d));
                outputPrice.setText("Price: " + x.format(purchasePrice));
            } else {
                double actualDiscount = purchasePrice * discount;
                outputDiscountAmount.setText("Dicount: " + x.format(actualDiscount));
                //discountAmount = purchasePrice - Double.parseDouble(outputDiscountAmount.getText());
               discountAmount = purchasePrice - actualDiscount;
                outputPrice.setText("Price: " + x.format(discountAmount));

                //Not sure whether the discountAmount variable should be in the "else" 
                //brackets or at the top.  If it is at the top nothing works.
                //If where it is presently seen, outputDiscountAmount works, but outputPrice doesn't.
                //Don't know what's wrong.
            }
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Please enter some amount");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource().equals(discountButton)){
            discountButtonActionPerformed(e);           
        }
    }

    public static void main (String []args){
        new PriceDiscountSwing();
    }
}
```